# Sharing git pull privileges between Private Github repo + pythonanywhere

Tags: github, pythonanywhere

I'm figuring out the best practice for sharing `git pull origin` privileges for other collaborators. My team has access to both my private repo + the pythonanywhere project in question.

1. [I followed these steps](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ExternalVCS) to get my ssh keys setup
2. Then I created a personal access token in my github account

Every time I want to pull the origin from my git repo to pythonanywhere, I'm asked for my password. Ideally, I'd like to create some kind of password or privileges that's only associated with this particular repo (not all of my private repos). My bash console in pythonanywhere looks like this:

I'm pretty new to cloud deployments + collaborative Python dev in general, so any feedback is appreciated!

[image: Have to enter password like this every time]

Comment: *Git* has no kind of authentication or protection. Hosting sites like Git*Hub* add some on, for obvious reasons; the details depend on the hosting site. So this is a GitHub question, not a Git question. I've updated your tags.

Comment: @Doug It's because you have probably still set http url as the remote, you should use ssh one instead (if you click on the  "Clone" button on GitHub in the project, you will see the options).

Comment: @casenueve that was exactly right!! If you wanna leave an answer I'll mark it for ya :)